# Python gmail oauth SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, gmail, archlinux, oauth2client

I'm on arch linux.

Copied the gmail example from: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

The code is working well on Ubuntu, but on arch I have this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmail.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "gmail.py", line 58, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "gmail.py", line 46, in get_credentials
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 231, in run_flow
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2138, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1059, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Tested urllib2 with other https and it's working well.

I have no clue on which could be the problem.